# Trouble linking to same page - if statement with _GET not working

Tags: php, url, dynamic, get

I have some code that looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <aside class="sidebar">
        <a href="index.php?Cat=members"><h3>Members</h3></a>
        <a href="index.php?Cat=prodcat"><h3>Product Categories</h3></a>
    </aside>
<article class="content">
    <section>
        <?php
        echo $_GET["Cat"];
        if ($_GET["Cat"] = 'members'){
            $membership = New Membership();
            $membership->member_List($sort);
        }
        else if ($_GET["Cat"] = 'prodcat'){
            $membership = New Membership();
            $membership->prodcat_List();
        }
        else {
        echo 'Welcome';
        }
        ?>
       </section>
    </article>
</div>
```

What should happen, is that when the link Members is pressed. The page should reload itself and show only what is brought back from the member_list.
Or if the product categories link is then pressed - it should then show whatever comes back from prodcat_list.

The problem is. Once I load the index page whatever comes back from the member_list appears straight away. Despite no 'Cat' being declared in the URL. Once this happens, I cannot then use the links to change it.

As you can see I have an echo for the $_GET["Cat"]. It is changing every time the page changes.

However the rest of the page is not. I have no idea why. Nor can I work out how to fix this. If I swap the if/else if statements around. I can get the prodcat_list to appear. But then I have the same problem trying to get the member_list to appear. NFI what is going on. Im only an amateur with PHP. Getting better every day though. But I've a long way to go.

EDIT

I'm an idiot. Thanks everybody! ==

Comment: Is that a typo you have there, or are you actually trying to compare (`==`) using the assignment operator `=`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
if ($_GET["Cat"] = 'members'){
```

should be like this

```
if ($_GET["Cat"] == 'members'){
```

Note the `==` instead of your `=`! Likewise in the other if clauses later on.

If you use just a single `=`, you actually do an assignment. So in your case, in the if clause you try to assign the value `member` to the variable `$_GET["Cat"]`. As there is nothing wrong with that assignment, it is executed and the if-clause evaluates to `true`.

For comparisons use `==` or `===`. The single `=` is just for assignments!

Comment: OHHHH
God damnit how did I miss that.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`=` means assignment `==` means comparison.
If you want to compare `$_GET['Cat']` with another string you must use the comparison operator.

Also when `index.php` is open for the first time, using `$_GET['Cat']` will produce a notice (undefined index) because `$_GET['Cat']` will not be defined. Use `if(isset($_GET['Cat']))` to fix this.

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 Though, actually, PHP emits a *notice* of an undefined index, not a warning...

Answer (score 0):

Your Code has an mistake:

in the if-statement you should use the double "=" für commparison like

```
if ($_GET["Cat"] == 'prodcat')
```